# How to have multiple values inside a CSS tilde attribute selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to select a list elements by using a tilde attribute selector with multiple values.

If I put only one value like this, it works fine:

```
a[class~="logo1"] {
    background: gold;
}
```

But, if I put it like this (my goal is to have multiple values), it doesn't work:

```
a[class~="logo1 logo2"] {
    background: gold;
}
```

On the MDN page I read a value can be a **whitespace-separated list** of words. But I'm probably making a syntax error, since it doesn't work.

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/kodplay/pen/GRQEeOE?editors=1100

Thank you!

Comment: per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)
`Represents elements with an attribute name of attr whose value is a whitespace-separated list of words, one of which is exactly value.` so this is for attributes other than classes (which are an edge case in this scenario), where there's a number of words in an attribute's value, and you want to match on one of them. (and not all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the new selector [`:is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is)

```css
a:is(.logo1, .logo2) {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#internal" id="internal">Internal link</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://example.com" class="logo1">Logo 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#InSensitive" class="logo2">Logo 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://example.org">Example org link</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://example.org">Example https org link</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://temp.org">Example exact match</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write multiple selectors combining with ','

```
a[class~="logo1"],a[class~="logo2"] {
    background: gold;
}
```